# Can't find SmartGlass in Windows 8 App Store

Tags: windows-8, xbox360, windows-store

In [microsoft pages](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/smartglass/smartglass-setup) they are saying:

> Download and Install SmartGlass from the Windows Store
>
> Open the Start screen on your Windows-based device or PC. Select
>   Windows Store. Open the Entertainment category. Choose the Xbox
>   SmartGlass app. Click Install. When the installation completes, an
>   Xbox SmartGlass tile is available on your Start screen.

I searched, but it's not appearing in the store for me:

[image]

Is there a direct link for it?

Comment: Depending on which country you're in, your MS Store may not have that app (yet).

Comment: @techie007 yes, this seams my case.

Comment: Use magicandre's solution

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a search ;-)

Go to MS Store -> move mouse to the right side of you screen (contextual menu with settings will slide out) search is the first item -> type smartglass -> it's the first link

It's not intuitive but the search is ALWAYS contextual i.e. when you search on the home screen, it will search your computer, when in store it will search apps, when in music it will search you music/MP3

makes sense?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: it is not appearing on mine http://screencast.com/t/mvtGl85mpJ1

Comment: Any chance that you are in a country that is currently "restricted". Set your location to the USA and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link:

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/571b1120-f579-47d3-88c8-a722652643b3

[image]

Open it with IE or Firefox, and you get a link, **View in Windows Store**. Click on it and install the App in the store.

The search in the store is ugly. I use this website for search:

http://metrostorescanner.com/

Comment: IE or Firefox will work. Both show View in Windows Store.